# How to get git tag for a commit hash in a remote repository?

Tags: git

You can get the tag which points at a particular commit in your local repository by doing this:

```
git tag --points-at <commit-hash>
```

or this:

```
git describe --exact-match <commit-hash>
```

Is this possible for a remote repository too, without even cloning the repository?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git ls-remote -t <remote> | grep <commit-hash>
```

`git ls-remote` lists all the refs and their sha1 values in the remote repository. `-t` limits to tags only. If you are under a local git repository, and the remote is `origin`, `<remote>` can be omitted. You can run the command anywhere if you specify `<remote>` like `https://github.com/foo/bar.git`. `-t` must come before `<remote>` if `<remote>` exists in the command. See more at [git-ls-remote](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html).

**Update:**

No, there is not something like `--points-at` for `git ls-remote`. If you know a tag name, `git ls-remote <remote> <tag_name>` returns the sha and the tag, but not possible from a sha to a tag name.

There are two types of tags. One is a lightweight tag, and the other is an annotated tag. The formmer is only a ref and the latter is a git object. Git has four kinds of objects, `commit`, `tag`, `tree` and `blob`.

If `v1.0` is a lightweight tag, `v1.0` and `v1.0^{}` are the same.

If `v1.0` is an anotated tag, `v1.0` is a tag object and `v1.0^{}` is the commit it refers to. As an anotated tag, `v1.0` and `v1.0^{}` are the same for many git commands, for example `git log`, `git show`, `git diff`, when they are resolved as `commit` or `tree`. In `git log v1.0`, `v1.0` is a `commit-ish`. As a `commit-ish`, `v1.0` and `v1.0^{}` refer to the same commit. So we get the same output from `git log v1.0` and `git log v1.0^{}`. For other git commands like `git rev-parse`, they are different. In `git rev-parse -t v1.0`, `v1.0` is a tag object. And in `git rev-parse -t v1.0^{}`, `v1.0^{}` is a commit object.

Comment: Thanks. But, I'll have to somehow parse the result. Is there a way to get just the tag name as we get with {git tag --points-at <commit-hash>}. Also, what is the difference between v1.0 and v1.1^{} ?