# How to programmatically get the Tags or branch name remotely from hash value using java libs for git api?

Tags: java, git, github, gitlab

I have searched in [JGIT Api](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/documentation/), [EGIT Doc](http://javadox.com/org.eclipse.mylyn.github/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/2.1.4/overview-summary.html), [kohsuke git api doc](http://github-api.kohsuke.org/apidocs/index.html)

Please can anyone guide me on this?

I also thought a workaround to get the tag using the sha1 hash(40 character) by running a git command via programmatically as mentioned in another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46536503/2018343) post. At least are any of above api permits to run a git command?

Comment: Have you tried the git api? Just get the remote refs name and pass it into the git api to get the commit. Tags work too because they are got refs.

Comment: Some pointers would help.

Comment: I am new to all these.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jgit

Answer (score 1):

You might try and compare that hash with known tag, using the [GitHub API for commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits).

I suggested that in "[GitHub API: Tag a commit belongs to ( parallel for `git describe --tag <sha>`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31668477/6309)".
I don't see a more direct API.

Answer (score 1):

Usually what you'll want to do here is the equivalent of a `git ls-remote` on the remote in question and then find the name based on the reference.  Note that it's possible to have multiple references with the same hash, so you'll need to have some way of deciding which one you want.  The hash may also not point to any ref, and you'll need to clone the repository if you want something like `master~2` as a response.

It doesn't look like JGit has an option for this explicitly, but it does have the LsRefsV2 API operation for protocol v2, which may meet your needs.  You can search for `git ls-remote` equivalents in your preferred API, and you'll probably find some help there.